# Multiple foreign keys in single table not generating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a setup where when I user creates a new project they by default must create a new team that belongs to the project (one-to-one) and a new role that belongs to the team (many-to-one).  Everything works as expected except I also want the person who creates the project tied to the first role.

Role therefore has two foreign keys (team_id and user_id).  I cannot seem to get user_id to populate like team_id is.  Here is the code:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_or_admin_user,  only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


  def new
    @user = current_user
    @project = Project.new
    @team = @project.build_team
    @user.roles.build 
    @team.roles.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.new(params[:project])

    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Your new project has been created!"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Is there something wrong with the line "current_user.roles.build?  I don't understand why @team.roles.build is working but not this other line.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand, but am I right that you want the *same* role to belong to both the current user and the newly created team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-when_are_objects_saved

I see two problems here:

1. `build` does not save the created object. The role you build with the association to the new team gets saved when the team gets saved (when rails knows what the team's id is, so that it can set the foreign key). Similarly, the team gets saved when the new project gets saved. So those saves all happen when you save the project. But you don't ever do anything that would result in the role you build with the user association being saved.
2. Even if you used `create` (which saves the new associated record), i.e., `@user.roles.create`, you wouldn't end up with what I think you want, because you'd be creating a different `Role` object than the one you get from `@team.roles.build`.

Something like the following would solve both of these issues.

```
@team.roles << @user.roles.build
```

Comment: When I attempt to add this line into the new method it creates another role instance in the form and when I save the project it still does not register the user_id in either of the role table entries.  If I were to put this in create I am not sure how I could pass the team instance between the methods.  Would a Save be needed as well or should Project.save still take care of this?  I assume the '<<' appends the build association once @team.roles is recognized in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what you were getting at with '@team.roles << @user.roles.build'.  I was not able to use @team.roles though because the scope of this instance was limited to the new function as far as I could tell.  Also the creation of this foreign key has to take place in create because the role is not generated until after the project is saved.

What I ended up doing was I added the following to the create method after the if @project.save line:

```
          current_user.roles << @project.team.roles(params[:project])
```

Then I removed @user.roles.build completely.  Section 4.3.1.2 from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference is where it all finally clicked for me.

Comment: Great! Glad I could provide a hint that helped you figure it out for yourself; sorry I wasn't around over the holidays to follow up.